# Can't make a derived instance of Num

Tags: haskell, ghci, newtype, derived-instances

I am using `ghci`, this code section

```
newtype Gold = Gold Int
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)
```

is showing the error as

```
Can't make a derived instance of 'Num Gold':
  'Num' is not a derivable class
  Try GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving for GHC's newtype-deriving extension in the newtype declaration for 'Gold'
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: As said by GHC's error message: add `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` to the top of your file.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I think the OP didn't know _how_ to turn on extensions, hence the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can only derive from `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show` and `Read` automatically. In order to derive other instances, you need to enable the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension as GHCi suggests:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Gold = Gold Int
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)
```

Note that the `{-# ... #-}` isn't a comment, but a [compiler pragma](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch12.html), in this case enabling the given language extension.

Comment: Error Message shows: Can't make a derived instance of 'Num Gold':
 Num is not a derivable class
 Try GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving for GHC's newtype-deriving extension
 In the newtype declaration for 'Gold'

Comment: Thank you @MathematicalOrchid. I am very new to Haskell. Actually I didn't include the line {-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving #-}.

Comment: @milleniumbug No need to be rude. The OP could be forgiven for thinking it was a comment, given the syntax.